# PhD admissions - Contacting multiple profs from the same university

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, email

Presently, I am writing to potential PhD guides in US universities. There are two professors from the same department who work on topics that cannot be considered closely related, but I would be happy to work under either of them.

I have already written to one of them, who has asked me to go ahead with the application process. I am now wondering whether I should mention in my mail that this (contact with first prof) has already been established, while still conveying that I am adequately interested.

Upon a positive reply from the second prof, what would be the best way to talk about both profs in my Statement of Purpose? I want to keep both options open, while not being rejected because the admissions office/the professors thought I wasn't specific enough with my application.

Comment: I am currently having the same question. Did you contact the second supervisor finally? Did you mention that you have talked with the first supervisor?

Comment: No, I did not contact.

Comment: May I know is it because you got the reply of the first one or you were afraid of those issues you mentioned above (these are exactly my concerns)?

Comment: After getting encouraging replies from other universities, I decided not to apply for the second professor. So, it's more the first case I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are no answers yet on this question because there is no problem here; being interested in two different research groups is acceptable.  In fact, interest in just one group increases your chances of rejection since that group may be full.