# Applying for PhD position to multiple professors in the same department

Tags: phd, advisor

I got interviewed by a potential supervisor but she said she couldn’t accept me because I have no research experience related to her projects. I still want to do research in her field; so I contacted some supervisor from the same department as her and will be interviewed next week.

I want to know if it is ok to contact another supervisor from the same department if she finds out about it.

Comment: Related: [PhD admissions - Contacting multiple profs from the same university](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/30853/7734).

Comment: Well, all I can say is *Academia is a small world*.

Answer (score 6):

It is ok, since she already told you no. It is your right to find new one and to apply to us many as possible positions. 
I think you should know that if you would like to work on someone's projects, it is highly desirable to have experience.

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty Okay! I have faced the same situation. One professor rejected me, then I contacted to another, who accepted my candidature, and gave me an offer.
There is nothing bad doing so. Go ahead. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Its absolutely fine. even if she did not give you a definite no and she told you that she has to think about it or she is not sure about her funding and stuff you are still free and fine to approach other people in her department. However, if you were asked that have you applied to anyone else to that department you should tell the truce. And it MIGHT even help to mention if you have a non-negative feedback from other colleagues in the department who do not have funding.